# Post A Json object as parameter value in Swift 4 ios using Alamofire

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

I am trying many ways but every time i was failed.
i want to post json object as key value
key is "data"
key value is

```
{"totalcost":"8500","delivery_type":"take_away","order_name":"","order_mobilenumber":"","order_city":"Chose Your Place","order_address":"","take":"  2 Hour ","":[{"parent_id":"145","subitem_id":"179","quentity":"1"}],"customer_id":"6"}
```

and My code is

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "data":
            ["customer_id":"6",
            "totalcost":"8500",
            "delivery_type":"take_away",
            "order_name":"",
            "order_mobilenumber":"",
            "order_city":"Chose Your Place",
            "order_address":"",
            "take_away_time":" Next 2 Hour ",
            "":[
                [
                  "parent_id":"145",
                  "subitem_id":"179",
                  "quentity":"1"
                ]
            ]
        ]

    ]

Alamofire.request("http:/app_con",method:.post,parameters:parameters,encoding:JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{response in
        let jsonResult = response.result.value
        print(jsonResult)

    }
```

and i am getting below response

```
{
message = "Please Try After Some Time";
status = error;
```

}

But through post man i am getting below response

```
{
message = "successfully submitted";
status = successful;
```

})

i tried many ways , nothing is worked out for me . please give me your valuable suggestions .

Thank You

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: i am posting same pameters in postman , it give response as 'status : "Successful"'

Comment: but through above code ,Getting Status error

Comment: Please add your error in your question.

Comment: There is no error ,It is not giving successful response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It was solved by using SwiftyJson. I searched many sites but I did not get expected answer.
I am posting the answer because it will be useful for someone

Solution is

```
I tried to post key value in dictionary format instead of json format,That's why i did not get expected output. swiftjson is very to write json object.**

let emptyJson : JSON = JSON(["customer_id":"26",
                                 "totalcost":"8500",
                                 "delivery_type":"take_away",
                                 "order_name":"",
                                 "order_mobilenumber":"",
                                 "order_city":"Chose Your Place",
                                 "order_address":"",
                                 "take_away_time":" Next 2 Hour ",
                                 "":[
                                    [
                                        "parent_id":"145",
                                        "subitem_id":"179",
                                        "quentity":"1"
                                    ]
                                    ]
                               ])
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "data": emptyJson
    ]
Alamofire.request("http://_con",method:.post,parameters:parameters).responseJSON{response in
        let jsonResult = response.result.value
        print(jsonResult)

    }
```

And There is no need to use json encoding in Alamofire request.we just are posting json object.